# grab the detail from particular location from file in c++

Tags: c++

```
char a[133];
char x[4]="ccc";
    int line=3,count=1;

    //string aa;
    //cin>>aa;
    ifstream out("text");


    while(out.getline(a,4,':')&&(strncmp(a,x,4)))
            {cout<<"hi";
                    cout<<a<<endl;
            out.getline(a,4,'\n');
}
out.close();
return 0;`
```

in text file

```
aaa:1111111
bbb:222222
ccc:333333
ddd:444444
```

i want to jump on particular line and grab the detail. but i did not get it. please guide me how to do it in c++

After all got the solution. You can see the result also

here it is

```
int main(){
    ifstream in ("text");
    if(!in){cout<<"cannot open"<<endl;}
    string buffer;
    int line_count=1; size_t line=1;
    while(line){
      getline(in,buffer);
      if(!buffer.find_first_of("bbb:"))
      {
         cout<<line<<endl;
         break;
      }
      else
      {
       line=line+1;
      }
    }

    cout<<buffer<<endl;
    for(int line_count=0;line_count<line-1&&getline(in,buffer);line_count++)
    {
    }

    getline(in,buffer);

    in.close();
    return 0;
 }
```

thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could read each line into an `std::string` like this:

```
std::ifstream in("text");
std::string buffer;
int line_count = 0;

// discard lines until we arrive at the desired line or an error/eof occurs
for(int line_count = 0; 
    line_cout < line && std::getline(in, buffer);
    line_count++) {}

if(in) { // check if last extraction was successful
    // process line stored in buffer
}
else {
    if(in.eof())
        std::cout << "Line-number was invalid" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "An error occurred" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

You can find some details on reading files using `iostreams` [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.4).
Then you can process that line. Using the member-function `std::string::find_first_of` you can find the `':'`, and using the member-function `std::string::substr` you can split the string at that position.

Note that this method only works for simple formats like described in your question. For formats like `"ab:c":"content"` it would not work as you probably expect. If you have such formats, you'd need to write a more complex parser, preferably using [`Boost.Spirit.Qi`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html).

Comment: thank you vey much for your reply. But what if we do not know the line number. we just know that we want detail of 'bbb' line.  thanks again

Comment: You can check if a line starts with a given string using `std::string::find_first_of(const std::string&)` - it will return `0` if the line starts with the given string. So, for example, `buffer.find_first_of("bbb:")` would return `0` for the second line in your example, and a non-zero value for all other lines.